# the completeness of Lebesgue measurable space

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose that a sequence $E_1,E_2,\cdots$ of measurable sets on $[0,1]$ satisfies the Cauchy condition, so that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N>0$ such that $m(E_n \bigtriangleup E_m)<\varepsilon $, for all $n,m\geq N$. Prove that there exists a measurable set $E$ on $[0,1]$ such that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}m(E_m \bigtriangleup E)=0$ Here $A \bigtriangleup B= (A\setminus B)\cup (B \setminus A)$.

Comment: Right. I revised it.

Comment: Would it be cheating to let $f_n = 1_{E_n}$ and note that $\|f_n-f_m\|_1 = m(E_m \bigtriangleup E_n)$? (And use completeness of $L_1[0,1]$.)

Comment: I have the same idea at first, but how can you prove the equivalence of these two spaces?